# Hide TableView declared in other class

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, object, hidden

How to hide my tableView which is declared in another class..

Here is my code snippet,

`CRStoreView.h`

```
@interface CRStoreView : UIView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
            ....
  }

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblStore;
```

and i want to hide this `tblStore` in my new class(CRNextView.m)..

I tried this but table is not getting hide,

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    NSLog(@"touchesBegan");
    CRStoreView *Obj = [[CRStoreView alloc] init];
    [Obj.tblStore setHidden:YES];
}
```

**How to Solve it ?**

Comment: U r creating a new object of CRStoreView rather(assuming that its not a Singleton Class), u shall take the instance which is already created some where and added to the view/window.

Comment: You need to pass the instance of CRStoreView and hide the tableview. Creating new instance won't hide existing tableview

Comment: You will need to use a delegate. You are creating a new instance of the CRStoreView

Comment: how do you init the firt time the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use delegates. Make `CRStoreView` a delegate of the `CRNextView` and call the  `setHidden` method from the `CRNextView` on the delegate. Or you could pass the current instance of the `CRStoreView` to `CRNextView` and access the tableView object.